# MongoDB query criteria not working correctly Meteor / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a Products collection with an attribute called "productCode". I am trying to write a server-side query to return a product based on the productCode attribute, but I keep getting a "cannot read property 'propertyCode' of undefined" error.

Here is my method call:

```
Meteor.call('findProduct', searchVal, function(error, a) {
        if(error) {
            alert(error.reason)
        } else {
            console.log('search success!');
        }
    });
```

Here is my methods.js code that is giving me that error:

```
'findProduct': function(searchVal, a) {
    a = Products.findOne({productCode: searchVal});
    return a; //return the product of interest
}
```

Error: Exception in delivering result of invoking 'findProduct': TypeError: Cannot read property 'productCode' of undefined

However, if I hard code in the product code, it works:

```
'findProduct': function(searchVal, a) {
    a = Products.findOne({productCode: 9021073});
    return a; //this will return the product
}
```

In my terminal console, this works as well:

```
db.products.findOne({productCode: 291105300});
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean "cannot read property `'productCode'` of undefined" or is it really 'propertyCode' in the error you are getting?

Comment: How the the method being called? Why pass in the second parameter if it isn't being used? In which console are you seeing the error (browser or terminal)?

Comment: @boombox i updated my question with the exact error (copy & pasted from browser console)

Comment: @DavidWeldon I updated my question with my method call. I am seeing the error in my browser console. My terminal console says 'undefined'

Comment: Check your "searchVal" if you're passing in the right value when you do your Meteor.call().

Comment: @boombox I've checked that both in the browser and terminal console - they both print the correct searchVal

Comment: Also, for readability alone: quote field names, please.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - the reason is initially a string. I converted it to an Integer using parseInt and it worked!